# Three radio button for each element

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Here is a function that adds radio buttons to each element.

```js
function createRadioButtons(buttons, checked, name, where) {
  buttons.forEach((el) => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.id = el.toLowerCase();
    input.name = name;
    input.value = el.toLowerCase();

    if (el.toUpperCase() === checked.toUpperCase()) {
      input.checked = true;
    }

    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = el;
    label.htmlFor = el.toLowerCase();

    where.appendChild(input);
    where.appendChild(label);
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach((el) => {
  createRadioButtons(['no', 'maybe', 'yes'], 'maybe', 'answer', el);
});
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

The `name` attribute of the first three radio buttons should be `answer1`, the `name` attribute of the second set of buttons should be `answer2`, and the `name` attribute of the third set of buttons should be `answer3`.

I think we should do it something like this:

```js
function createRadioButtons(buttons, checked, name, where, i) {
   i++;
   the rest of the code
}

document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach((el) => {
  let i = 0;
  createRadioButtons(['no', 'maybe', 'yes'], 'maybe', 'answer', el, i);
});
```

However, when I tried it, I ended up with something wrong, like `answer1` for each `no` button and `answer2` for each `maybe` button.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forEach` callback function receives the array index as the second argument. Use that in the `name` argument.

```js
function createRadioButtons(buttons, checked, name, where) {
  buttons.forEach((el) => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.id = el.toLowerCase();
    input.name = name;
    input.value = el.toLowerCase();

    if (el.toUpperCase() === checked.toUpperCase()) {
      input.checked = true;
    }

    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = el;
    label.htmlFor = el.toLowerCase();

    where.appendChild(input);
    where.appendChild(label);
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach((el, index) => {
  createRadioButtons(['no', 'maybe', 'yes'], 'maybe', 'answer' + (index+1), el);
});
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Barmar answered my question yesterday and his answer is correct in the sense that it resolves the issue with the `name` attribute.

However, as I have noticed just now, there is another thing to fix. When you click a *label* in the first or second group, it switches the input in the *third* group. This is wrong, of course.

So I think the code should be like this:

```js
function createRadioButtons(buttons, checked, name, where, index) {
  buttons.forEach((el) => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.id = el.toLowerCase() + index;
    input.name = name + index;
    input.value = el.toLowerCase() + index;

    if (el.toUpperCase() === checked.toUpperCase()) {
      input.checked = true;
    }

    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = el;
    label.htmlFor = el.toLowerCase() + index;

    where.appendChild(input);
    where.appendChild(label);
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach((el, index) => {
  createRadioButtons(['no', 'maybe', 'yes'], 'maybe', 'answer', el, index);
});
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```